# Valgrind: How to understand exactly when I lose control of a pointer to a memory location

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am using the [valgrind's](http://valgrind.org/) tool [memcheck together with GDB](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands) trying to track down a memory leak in my C code.

Valgrind found where the memory was allocated but the pointer to this memory is tossed around a lot in the code before it is free'd. About 99 % of the time this is free'd correctly but sometimes it isn't. Can Valgrind, in some way, help me to find exactly where I lose control of this pointer or do I need to look into this extremely complex code to find it by myself?

**Edit:** If it is not possible for Valgrind to give me this information I would be happy if someone could tell me why. I mean Valgrind does have the information about where the memory is allocated and if I stop the program with GDB and ask for a leak check it will know if I have lost this the pointer to this memory. Why can't valgrind "watch" this pointer and tell me exactly when I lose it?

Comment: You'll certainly have to look at the code, but I thought isolating the leak is what valgrind does.

Comment: Look for all instances when that pointer is assigned to something else or an exception occurs. That should account for most leaks.

Comment: You can run your program "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --db-attach=yes ./a.out". This way your program would automtically be attached with gdb. This might be useful and you can do live debugging and check most information.

Comment: @tmp as I said I am already doing that =)

Answer (score 2):

The Valgrind Omega tool does this: it shows where the last pointer to your leaked memory is lost. Unfortunately the tool [is disabled since Valgrind 3.4](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html):

> exp-Omega, an experimental instantaneous leak-detecting tool, was 
>   disabled in 3.4.0 due to a lack of interest and maintenance, although
>   the source code was still in the distribution. The source
>   code has now been removed from the distribution.

So you'd have to download and build Valgrind 3.3, and then you can run `valgrind --tool=exp-omega`.

Links:

- [Homepage of Valgrind Omega](http://www.brainmurders.eclipse.co.uk/omega.html)
- [Old Valgrind releases](http://valgrind.org/downloads/old.html)
- looks like the 3.3.0 release isn't available from that site any more, but Google found [this one](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/valgrind/valgrind-3.3.0.tar.bz2/e5fc39755a714f36b7e5014c1c6d4748/valgrind-3.3.0.tar.bz2) (md5 sum matches)

Comment: Oh, that sounds very promising. But I can't believe that such a useful tool is removed. I always spend a lot of time finding where the memory is lost. I will try this tool when I have time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cannot install valgrind 3.3. It says "configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6". I think my kernel is 3.5 :/

Comment: You might be able to patch the `configure` file to disable this check. With luck, Valgrind works on 3.5 the same as it does on 2.6.

Comment: If I patch that I fail with some other checks and I think that keeping  patching the configure file to ignore checks will probably not result in something working

Comment: I just found out that they are actually discussing if they should implement Omega in memcheck: https://fosdem.org/2014/schedule/event/valgrind_bof/
But I don't know the outcome of the meeting.